# What extent of difference is considered significant in runtime?

Tags: functional-programming

I have a task to test the time required to evaluate a specialised function and a generalized function that aims to get the same output, and conclude whether there is a speed advantage of using one over the other. It turns out that the time in milliseconds differ by roughly 0.835ms. My question is whether a difference of 0.835ms is considered significant in the programming world to be called a speed advantage? If this is insignificant, is there a value that is considered significant so that I have a better idea?

Comment: It is significant if the method is run a million times an hour. It is insignificant if it is run once a month. The thing that tells you its significance is the context in which it runs. So yes, it can be significant, or it can be insignificant. It could save millions of dollars in processing time a year, or be more trouble than it is worth to implement.

Comment: Depends on the total time the operations take to run.  0.835ms is small if they take hours and large if they take on the order of a few ms.